# Change default success URL in Spring Security using Vaadin 21

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow

currently I am playing around with Vaadin 21 and especially with the better integration of Spring Security.
I followed the Spring security tutorial for Vaadin 21 and flow on https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control . However I need to change the defaultSuccesUrl/successUrl from "" to "/application", because currently after login I will always get routed to "/" which soes not exist. I already played around a lot but I was not successfully.

This is the configure method of my Security config:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.rememberMe().alwaysRemember(false);

    // Current
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/VAADIN/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/services/**").permitAll();

    // Set the login processing url
    http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl(ApplicationUrl.APP_LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL);

    // Set the default success Url
    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl(ApplicationUrl.APP);

    // Set the default failure Url
    http.formLogin().failureUrl(ApplicationUrl.APP_LOGIN_FAILURE_URL);

    super.configure(http);

    // This is important to register your login view to the
    // view access checker mechanism:
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
}
```

I already put http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl(ApplicationUrl.APP_LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL); after super.configure(http) and changed to http.formLogin().successForwardUrl(ApplicationUrl.APP); but nothing worked.

Hopefully someone can give me a hint how to solve this. In Vaadin 14 this was no problem, because there, you must configure it "manually".

Thanks,
Florian

Comment: Not a solution to the problem but you should configure a RouteAlias for / that points to /application anyway. Otherwise your users will see an error message if the navigate to / in the browser.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. This must be a bug. Please add an issue https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues

Comment: Thank you, added issue: https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/867 added a route alias currently as workaround. Florian

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);
    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/foo");
}
```

Comment: http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/foo",true);